# How can I convert const char* to char[256]

Tags: c++

How do I convert `const char*` to `char[256]`?

```
const char *s = std::string("x").c_str();
char c[256] = /* ??? */
```

Comment: Why do `std::string("x").c_str()` when you can just do `"x"`? Yours causes a dangling pointer.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just for understanding code easily.

Comment: @Scott First, it's wrong.  Second, `const char* s = "x";` is more easily understandable.

Comment: It does matter. What you're doing is undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you doing all this because you're trying to call a function that takes a `char` array?  This has all the earmarks of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @solarflare `string("x")` is a temporary string object that will be destroyed at the end of the full expression. Doing `s = string("x").c_str()` makes `s` point to the inner string that will be destroyed, leaving `s` a dangling pointer at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot initialise an array with a character pointer. But you can copy the string. For example:

```
const char *s = get_the_string();
char c[256]{};
auto n = std::strlen(s);
if (std::size(c) <= n)
    throw std::runtime_error(
        "The buffer is too small. Contact your local C++ maintainer");
std::memcpy(c, s, n);
```

The obvious problem with using an array of constant size is that you need to consider how to handle situation where the input string doesn't fit. Here, I've used an exception, but you can use error handling of your choice, if this is not an option for you.

---

You cannot copy from a `const char *s = std::string("x").c_str();` though, because the pointer is dangling, and attempting to access the pointed data would have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @gman Abel's answer also (potentially) unnecessarily copies null characters into the buffer when the string is shorter. Even worse, it will leave the buffer non-null-terminated if the input string is longer than the buffer. That will lead to exploits, as you put it.

Comment: Yes, now that you've edited the code to address all the issues pointed out it seems correct.

Comment: It's funny you'd complain about copying null characters into the string though. His writes exactly 256 bytes. Yours writes 256 bytes into 'c' then copies n bytes into it. `strncpy(c, s, sizeof(c) - 1)` would do the minimal work. If you removed the `{}` then there would be no clearing but now you'd have a uninitialized buffer bug since you don't know what c will be used as a null terminated string later so the optimal answer is still `strncpy` except with sizeof(c) - 1 instead of sizeof(c) if null termination is important.

Comment: @gman Potentially, the optimal answer is still to not use `strncpy`, but write a single null terminator instead. But I chose to not show the optimal solution in my revised answer, because it doesn't apply to all use cases, and describing all solutions to all different use cases and their caveats is outside the scope of my answer. I'll save that for when I write a book on the subject :)

Comment: Sure, my point was it was hypocritical to criticize the strncpy answer doing extra work is since your own example does extra work.

Answer (score 2):

Copying the contents from the const type to an editable one is really your only recourse for dropping the const.  I'm guessing you are given a const because something has marked it "not ok for you to change" ie read only.

The trouble with a pure * though is you need to know how long it is.  For null-terminated strings, strlen can get you that size (and so it works with strncpy).

```
strncpy(c,s,256);
```

If the const char * were just bytes though, you'd need another way.

Comment: won't be null terminate if s is longer then 255 bytes

Comment: As it's an array you can do sizeof(c) to get its size and use it in via safe string functions that allow you to pass an n to them. You can also likely use 255 in place of 256 (if you init c to zeros and dont touch ther 255th item) or set the 255th element to '\0' explicitly if required.  Side note: to use in a printf, you can use something like "%.256s"

Comment: sizeof(c) only works if chars are 1byte. It's bad habit to use sizeof when you want to know how any elements not how many bytes

Comment: I believe sizeof is in fact tied to the sizeof a char (regardless of whether a char is 8 bits).  If not, please provide a reference.

Comment: That doesn't really matter. You should still use something that means "number of elements in arrays" not "number of storage units this array takes" which may or may not be coincidentally the same.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to copy a `const char*` into a `char[]`:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
const char *s = "x";
char c[256]{};
std::strncpy(c, s, 255);
```

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
const char *s = "x";
char c[256]{};
std::copy_n(s, std::min(std::strlen(s), 255), c);
```

```cpp
#include <string>
const char *s = "x";
char c[256]{};
std::string(s).copy(c, 255);
```

```cpp
#include <sstream>
const char *s = "x";
char c[256]{};
std::istringstream iss(s);
iss.read(c, 255);
//or: iss.get(c, 256, '\0');
```

Answer (score 1):

strncpy(c, s, 256);
it work for me

Comment: won't be null terminate if s is longer then 255 bytes

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out

```
const char *s = std::string("x").c_str();
```

Is bad code. It effectively creates a new string, puts "x" in it, returns a pointer to "x", frees the string. So now what `s` points to is undefined

If you were not creating the string in that line it would be safe. For example

```
const auto t = std::string("x");
const char *s = t.c_str();
```

Now `t` will be valid until the current scope exits and so will `s`

As for the copy to an array of 256 characters the arguably optimal solution is

```
char c[256];
std::strncpy(c, s, 255);
c[255] = '\0';
```

Why?

This line

```
char c[256];
```

allocates space on the stack for 256 bytes and does nothing else.

This line

```
std::strncpy(c, s, 255);
```

- if `s` is less than 255 characters it copies those characters into `c` then writes out zeros to pad out the buffer to the 254th element
- if `s` is 255 characters or more it just copies the first 255 characters

This line puts a null terminating zero at the end

```
c[255] = '\0';
```

Let's compare to other solutions

This one

```
    char c[256];
    std::strncpy(c, s, 256);
```

Problem with this answer is if s is more than 255 characters there will be no terminating 0 at the end of `c`. Whether that's important or not is really up to you but 999 times out of 1000 it probably is important.

This one

```
    char c[256]{};
    std::strncpy(c, s, 255);
```

Is safe but slower. The difference is the `{}` at the end of `char c[256]{}`. Without that `{}` the `c` array is only allocated. With it `c` is not only allocated but also initialized to 0 for all 256 characters. That means for every character copied from `s` to `c` there was a wasted effort clearing the character to zero at the beginning. That's potentially double the work

```
const char *s = get_the_string();
char c[256]{};
auto n = std::strlen(s);
if (std::size(c) <= n)
    throw std::runtime_error(
        "The buffer is too small. Contact your local C++ maintainer");
std::memcpy(c, s, n);
```

Same as above, does double the work though it is good to point out that you must choose how to handle `s` being too big to fit in `c`.

All of the examples using `char c[256]{}` instead of `char c[256]` are potentially doing double the work. Doing double the work is not necessarily bad but given the optimal version is simple there's no reason not to use it.

One other issue is using magic numbers. Unfortunately C++ didn't add an array size function until C++ 17 (std::size) so we're left to make our own

```
template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t array_size(T (&)[N]) { return N; }
```

so then we can do this

```
char c[256];
std::strncpy(c, s, array_size(c) - 1);
c[array_size(c) - 1] = '\0';
```

so now if we change the size of `c` the code will still work.

The standard version for getting the number of elements in an array is `std::size` added in C++ 17 but C++ 17 is apparently still rare, none of the online C++ compilers I tried (first several hits in Google) supported it.